# mysql prepared statements with special operators (addition, subtraction etc.)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, operators, prepared-statement

Would this scenario work:

```
$query = ' UPDATE users SET balance = (balance + ?) WHERE user = ? ';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

$sth->execute(array($rechargeamount, $username));
```

basically, a prepared statement for an amount followed by an addition operator.  Or would prepared statement have to include the "balance" value as well?

many thanks!

Comment: A crazy idea: try it. I bet that would have been faster than writing a question.

Comment: @cularis: his CPU charges him for each calculation he performs. So it is cheaper to ask here, perhaps :-S

Comment: I did try it, it was preparing, but was confused as to why it was not working. Kudos to Rikudo for an efficient and quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will work. Make sure you prepare out as an int (depends on which sql engine you're using)

Comment: how do you "prepare out as int" in the case of Mysql PDO? As the above is preparing fine, but the value which is a numeric float is not being added to the balance.

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':param', $param, PDO::PARAM_INT);`